# 'ValueError: day is out of range for month' as all the days have 31 days in all month in the data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working with 3-hourly satellite precipitation data. However, all the months have got 31 days.
I have gotten error while appending the datatime. Please help!

```
sat=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Amod\Documents\Dissertation\Data\MSWEP_INDIA_CITIES_FILTERED\data_11.375_75.875", sep=" ", header=None)


sat.columns = ["year", "month", "day", "satellite"]

years = list(sat.year)
months = list(sat.month)
days = list(sat.day)
rain = list(sat.satellite)

h = 0
datetimes = []
for i in range(len(years)):
    if i ==0:
        h = 0
    else:
        if days[i]==days[i-1]:
            h +=3 #h = h+1 is the same!
        else:
            h = 0
    datetimes.append(datetime.datetime(years[i], months[i], days[i], h))

datetimes

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-53553b0773c9> in <module>
     10         else:
     11             h = 0
---> 12     datetimes.append(datetime.datetime(years[i], months[i], days[i], h))
     13 
     14 datetimes

ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Comment: So there's a September 31st in the data?

Comment: There are 31 days in all months from 1979 to 2015, even February has got 31 days, regardless

Comment: All the months with 31 days (where the 31st date is not supposed to be there) has 0 precipitation. I tried removing 0's but many days contains 0 rainfall recorded. Therefore, it didn't really solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) and filtering out the non-dates but this can be dealt with with a try/except as below:

```
sat=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Amod\Documents\Dissertation\Data\MSWEP_INDIA_CITIES_FILTERED\data_11.375_75.875", sep=" ", header=None)



sat.columns = ["year", "month", "day", "satellite"]

years = list(sat.year)
months = list(sat.month)
days = list(sat.day)
rain = list(sat.satellite)

h = 0
datetimes = []
for i in range(len(years)):
    if i ==0:
        h = 0
    else:
        if days[i]==days[i-1]:
            h +=3 #h = h+1 is the same!
        else:
            h = 0
    try:        
        datetimes.append(datetime.datetime(years[i], months[i], days[i], h))
    except: continue
```

ETA:
To deal with errors in the datetime in pandas, check out the "Invalid Data" section [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = 'coerce')
df = df[df['Date'] != 'NaT']
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering! It did return me with correct datetimes. However, i couldn't change the datetime to Index.

sat = pd.DataFrame(rain, index=datetimes, columns=["satellite"])

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 102424), indices imply (1, 100536)


How can I use Pandas to filter out non-dates?
Thank you for your time